# Producing position function from two dimensions functions with respect to time

Tags: kinematics

At this page [enter link description here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/instantaneous-velocity/)

I found this solved problem " The $x$- and $y$-coordinates of a particle moving on the $xy$-plane at time ttt are given by the following equations:

$x(t) = 2t - 5$

$y(t) = -t^2 + 4t - 1$

My question is that is there a way to make these two functions of positions to be one function of position with respect to time.

Comment: They are already one function for position in two dimensions

Comment: I want to graph one position function with respect to time, I want to convert the two dimension into one position function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the position vector in two dimensions : $$\begin{align}\boldsymbol{r}(t)&=x(t)\textbf i + y(t)\textbf j\\
&=(2t-5)\textbf i+(-t^2+4t-1)\textbf j
\end{align}$$
$$\Rightarrow r(t)=\sqrt{{(2t-5)}^2+{(-t^2+4t-1)}^2}$$
which is one function pf position w.r.t. time.

Comment: I calculated the derivative of the final function of position you reached to to calculate the instantaneous velocity at t=1 like in the original problem in the site I mentioned in my question and it gave another answer other than the correct answer of the solved problem in that site I mentioned which was 2 \sqrt{2}

Comment: the first line is one function for position, but $r(t)$ is only distance, not position.

Comment: Right @Charles Francis . I wrote the distance just in addition.

Comment: I assumed that the second one is for displacement, yes, but I couldn't understand the first line form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to graph

$$
  \mathbf r(t)=  \begin{pmatrix}
    x(t) \\
    y(t)\\
    \end{pmatrix}
=  \begin{pmatrix}
    2t - 5 \\
    -t^2 + 4t - 1\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

you would really need three axes. Do you mean you want the distance travelled along the path? Then differentiate

$$
  \mathbf v(t)=  
 \begin{pmatrix}
    2  \\
    -2t + 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
find speed
$$v = |\mathbf v |= \sqrt{4 + 4t^2 -16t +16}= 2\sqrt{t^2 -4t +5} $$
then you could integrate to find distance along the curve.

Comment: Is it possible to graph the function of position as a function of position with one dimension with respect to time, is it possible or I must deal with the position function in 2D with x and y value, so I can't graph it as one function with respect to time?

Comment: It is still one function, but it must have both $x$ and $y$ values, and must be plotted in 2D plus a time axis.

Comment: I assumed that we can do it like the case of car motion which is in a road with many carves to left and right and although that we treat this case as one dimensional case. Thank you, I know now that I can't do it.